# how to pass the query parameters as default values in buildForm?

Tags: forms, 8

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // in D7 it was : $params = drupal_get_query_parameters();

$form['search_api_fulltext'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => $this->t('Faites une recherche'),
  // in D7 it was: '#default_value' => isset($params['search_api_fulltext'])?str_replace('+', ' ',$params['search_api_fulltext']):'',
);
$form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
$form['actions']['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => $this->t('Recherche'),
'#button_type' => 'primary',
);
return $form;


}
```

Comment: For clarity, are you talking about query parameters not under control of the FAPI?

Comment: euh, the parameters when this form is submitted.in other words,if a form submission have been made, i'd like to display in in the input the value entered

Comment: Form submission values are stored in `$form_state['values']`. This is how you would do it in Drupal 7 as well, but there's probably something else going on because you're using Search API and potentially there are HTTP Request query parameters being used. Would need more info on what you are trying to do.

Comment: \Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->query->all() ?

Answer (score 1):

there might be a better method as suggested in the comments.
I replaced

```
    $params = drupal_get_query_parameters();
```

by

```
    $params=\Drupal::request()->query->all();
```